# How to start GUI Application using Console Application in Java

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I created a console application using java and add a Menu to select the users what to do. And I created a simple GUI using another
class by simply extends it by Application. I need to start my GUI in my console application whenever the user selects to start it.
How can I do this?
console application

```
mport java.util.Scanner;

public class ConsoleApplication {
    private static LeagueManager leagueManager = new PremierLeagueManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //menu goes in
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        String select;
        loadFromFile();
        do {
            System.out.println("Premier League Manager");
            System.out.println("=================================");
            System.out.println("Please enter A to Add Football Club");
            System.out.println("Please enter D to Delete Football Club");
            System.out.println("Please enter S to Display Club Statistics");
            System.out.println("Please enter P to Display League Table");
            System.out.println("Please enter M to Add Played Match");
            System.out.println("Please enter Q to Exit");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice: ");
            select = scanner.nextLine();
            switch (select){
                case "A":
                case "a" :
                    addFootballClub();
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                case "D":
                case "d":
                    deleteFootballClub();
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                case "S":
                case "s":
                    displayStatistics();
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                case "P":
                case "p":
                    displayLeagueTable();
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                case "m":
                    addPlayedMatch();
                    exit = false;
                    break;
                case "Q":
                case "q":
                    saveToFile();
                    System.exit(0);
                    exit = true;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice! please try again");
                    exit = false;

            }
        }while (!exit);

    }

    public static void addFootballClub(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        String clubType = null;
        String inputClub;
```

GUI

```
        AnchorPane headerPane = new AnchorPane();
        headerPane.setId("header-pane");
        headerPane.setLayoutY(0);
        headerPane.setLayoutX(0);
        FileInputStream logoFile = new FileInputStream("assets/images/logo-design.png");
        Image logoImage = new Image(logoFile);
        ImageView logoView = new ImageView(logoImage);
        logoView.setLayoutX(0);
        logoView.setLayoutY(0);
        HBox btnHolder = new HBox(20);
        Label home = new Label("Home");
        home.setId("home");
        Label pointTable = new Label("Point Table");
        pointTable.setId("point-table");
        Label playMatch = new Label("Play Match");
        playMatch.setId("play-match");
        Label matches = new Label("Matches");
        matches.setId("matches");
        btnHolder.getChildren().addAll(home,pointTable,playMatch,matches);
        btnHolder.setLayoutY(40);
        btnHolder.setLayoutX(600);
        FileInputStream closeFile = new FileInputStream("assets/images/close.png");
        Image closeImage = new Image(closeFile);
        ImageView closeView = new ImageView(closeImage);
        closeView.setId("close-view");
        closeView.setLayoutY(10);
        closeView.setLayoutX(970);
        closeView.setOnMouseClicked( e -> primaryStage.close());
        headerPane.getChildren().addAll(logoView,btnHolder,closeView);
        AnchorPane contentPane = new AnchorPane();
        contentPane.setId("content-pane");
        contentPane.setLayoutX(0);
        contentPane.setLayoutY(100);
        AnchorPane textPane = new AnchorPane();
        textPane.setId("text-pane");
        Text description = new Text("The Premier League is the top tier of England's football pyramid," +"\n"+
                " with 20 teams battling it out for the honour of being crowned English champions.\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n"+
```

Comment: Could you share your code please? Are those 2 applications same project or different projects?

Comment: Bro I added the code. Same project but different classes

Comment: [mcve] please ... mind the __M__

Comment: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) is your friend :-) Something like: `Application.launch(GUI.class)`

Comment: thanks bro I did it